# Android - Changing Positive Button Text of EditTextPreference's Dialog Programmatically

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-edittext, android-dialog

I am trying to change the `positiveButtonText` of `Dialog` in the `EditTextPreference. I have tried the following with no success :

```
    // The reference to the preference in the view heirarchy
    mUrlPreference = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(pref);       
    // Add a textwatcher
    mUrlPreference.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(prefWatcher);
```

The `prefWatcher` is the following :

```
private TextWatcher prefWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.i(TAG_LOG, "Updating the positive button text");
        mUrlPreference.setPositiveButtonText("Download");
    }
};
```

When I change the text in the EditText, the Log gets printed, but the Positive button text is not changing. Is there anything I'm missing here? My initial thought was that I would have to refresh the dialog's view hierarchy, but I don't see any methods in the API to do it. Any ideas as to what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of [setPositiveButtonText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#setPositiveButtonText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), the updated text will be shown on subsequent dialogs. So to actually affect the button, do this instead:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    mUrlPreference.setPositiveButtonText("Download");

    Button button = (Button) mUrlPreference.getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
    button.setText("Download");
    button.invalidate(); // if necessary
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! But how did you get the id of the positive button?

Comment: @500865 BUTTON_POSITIVE was originally known as [BUTTON1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON1). The id is mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#button1).